# Python Mechanize - Get control by name in a page that has no forms

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I want to set a value to a select control but there is no form in the html, so when I try to get the component by name, like this:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.find_control(name="selectName").value = ["value"]
```

I get this message:

```
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'combo-disciplina-idigital-class'
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: what is 'br'? what framework are you using?

Comment: import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()

Comment: Where is the html?